# Setting a variable in Google Scripts based on another variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Javascript and slowing using Apps Scripts by google to practise, firstly, how do assign the value of a global variable to another one depending on if statements. Every test of the code below gives me the last value.

```
var oneweek = 8640, onefort = 4696, onemonth = 2628, threeweek = 7728, threefort = 4290, threemont = 2401;

var totalprice = 0;

switch (true) { 
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Weekly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = oneweek;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = oneweek / 2;
        break;
    }
    
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Fortnightly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = onefort;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = onefort / 2;
        break;
    }
  
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Monthly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = onemonth;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = onemonth / 2;
        break;
    }
    case (contract_len == "3 Years" && time_len == "Weekly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = threeweek;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = threeweek / 2;
        break;
    }
 
    case (contract_len == "3 Years" && time_len == "Fortnightly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = threefort;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = threefort / 2;
        break;
    }
  
    case (contract_len == "3 Years" && time_len == "Monthly"):
    if (day_options == "Full Day") {
        var totalprice = threemont;
    }
    else {
        var totalprice = threemont / 2;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to simplify this? I am using the on Submit form trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

The issue in your code is that you are not `break`ing when the first `if` condition holds true.

For example:

```
 switch (true) { 
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Weekly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = oneweek;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = oneweek / 2;
        break;
    }
    
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Fortnightly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = onefort;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = onefort / 2;
        break;
    }
```

If the first `case` statement is `true` and the first `if` statement as well, the value of `totalprice` will be equal to `oneweek`. The issue is that you forget to `break`. Therefore the next `case` block will be automatically `true`, and therefore `totalprice` will become `onefort` (assuming again that `day_options="Full Day"`).

That explains why you are getting the last value everytime.

The quick fix in your code is to put the `break` statement after the `if` blocks for **every** `case` statement.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var oneweek = 8640, onefort = 4696, onemonth = 2628, threeweek = 7728, threefort = 4290, threemont = 2401;
  contract_len = "1 Year"
  time_len = "Weekly"
  day_options = "Full Day"
  
  var totalprice = 0;

switch (true) { 
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Weekly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = oneweek;       
    }
        else {
          
          var totalprice = oneweek / 2;
    }
    break;
    
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Fortnightly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = onefort;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = onefort / 2;        
    }
    break;
  
    case (contract_len == "1 Year" && time_len == "Monthly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = onemonth;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = onemonth / 2;
    }
        break;
    case (contract_len == "3 Years" && time_len == "Weekly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = threeweek;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = threeweek / 2;
    }
       break;
 
    case (contract_len == "3 Years" && time_len == "Fortnightly"):
        if (day_options == "Full Day") {
          var totalprice = threefort;
    }
        else {
          var totalprice = threefort / 2;
        
    }
    break;
  
    case (contract_len == "3 Years" && time_len == "Monthly"):
    if (day_options == "Full Day") {
        var totalprice = threemont;
    }
    else {
        var totalprice = threemont / 2;
        
    }
    break;
  }
  
}
```

If you are looking to improve your code, this is not the right platform to request this. Instead I would advice you to post a question in the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

However, if you are looking to shorten your code, you can use [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).